# How secure is using Google account authentication with Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, login, security, authentication

I would like to know how secure is it to use Google account authentication for logging in to Stack Overflow and other sister sites.

Can one take any additional security measures?

Comment: I have seen buggy implementation of OpenID on the provider side, I doubt this will be the case for Google, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> With OpenID, your password is only given to your identity provider, and that provider then confirms your identity to the websites you visit.  Other than your provider, no website ever sees your password, so you don’t need to worry about an unscrupulous or insecure website compromising your identity.

[Full Source](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/)

Comment: Great to see that you've started participating in meta again :)

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles. I still think the same regarding Meta, The only reason [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137491/suggestion-how-to-handle-frequently-asked-questions) of mine, had **some effect** is because I left comments to several very active users in those tags, and still that question got 2 close votes. (I can see how the community here acts like a herd, if those users weren't come, the question was closed long time ago.) I don't think this answer is even close as helpful as [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134184/).

Comment: Of course, you're free to have you own opinion, but I feel rather bad that you've forsaken meta just due to a few bad experiences. Regarding your first link, it is obviously a dupe at first glance unless we know your intentions--which you stated in the comments. So of course you'd still get a few close votes from those who don't look close enough at the comments. Specifying that you knew of the duplicates, and why you were posting another question would be a good way to prevent close votes.

Comment: Regarding that answer, there were a few things that made it get downvoted. For one, most people didn't like the way you used the self-answer. Those points should have been in the question itself. So that may have made people already dislike the post. Then, most people support the current system, so of course you got downvotes there. And many people felt that the examples you used were baseless (see my answer there). So of course, with these three things against you, you got downvoted. Also, I don't see how it is "helpful". If it was part of the question it would be helpful. As an answer, no.

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles. [Another example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11223664/601179) to the list. showing that accepted answer is less than ideal.

Answer (score 12):

> Can one take any additional security measures?

Yeah - set up two-factor authentication for Google. Then someone has to steal your phone *and* your password to get into your Stack Overflow account.

(Also worth noting here - because this comes up *all the time* - that SE doesn't get access to anything on your Google account; Google tells us your email address and a unique ID so we can tell you apart from everyone else using Google to log in, and nothing else)

Comment: Right... Like you guys don't send emails from our gmail accounts. **We're not dumbs you know!**